# Default Component Grid Width

Tags: sxa

Is it possible to set the default grid width for a component out of the box in SXA? Let me explain the thought process behind this to hopefully highlight the problem.

I have a component that has four variants, each of these is designed to sit at a particular grid width. Is this something I can configure per variant (I am aware this is very unlikely) or failing that, potentially assign it per component?

As an example:

**Variant 1:** Default grid with of 4

**Variant 2:** Default grid width of 8

If either of my options are not possible, or highly not recommended, what options do I have in order to minimise the potential for user error when configuring component grid width?

---

**Environment Details**

SXA 1.8

Sitecore 9.1

---

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box.

What we did is setting `col-4` / `col-8` or specific `col-md-4` or `col-lg-4` respective classes on Rendering Variant level.

There is a field Css Class that will be combined with Css Class field on Rendering itself.

By this combination you can achieve what you want.

You can even use `Allowed in templates` field on your Rendering Variants to specify which one will be used on which template to help out content editors to choose correct Rendering Variant for that particular page.

Take a look here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/create-a-rendering-variant.html

Comment: Thanks very much!